# swift how can I check for NULL values coming from Json

Tags: json, swift, swift3, nsnull

I have a rest api and am getting all data via Json then putting it in a IOS TableView. My issue is that some data is being returned as `NULL` in Json

```
"vote_status":null
```

I am trying to get that `NULL` value in swift and change it to a string "0" but am having a hard time doing so . I have this so far

```
  if var vote_status = Stream["vote_status"] as? String {
                                if (vote_status == (vote_status)[NSNull]) {
                                   vote_status = "0"
                                }
}
```

However I get this compile error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type
>   '(NSNull).Type' (aka 'NSNull.Type')

I am doing this because **nil** and **null** does not seem to work so I can't do this.

```
if (vote_status == nil) ...
```

Comment: If you print the dictionary you're getting from the JSON to the console, what do you see?

Comment: if I print it; it does not return anything at all not even NULL it's just blank

Comment: There is no way to answer this unless we know how you are converting the JSON string into an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to conditionally cast your dictionary value to String and use the Nil Coalescing Operator `??` to assign `"0"` in case of failure `null`:

```
let vote_status = Stream["vote_status"] as? String ?? "0"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

```
func checkNull(obj : AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
    if obj is NSNull {
        return nil
    } else {
        return value
    }
}

object.feature = checkNull(dict["feature"])
```

try this

```
vote_status is NSNull
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
func checkForNull(value:AnyObject) -> String
    {
        if(value as! NSObject == NSNull() || value as! String == "")
        {
           return " "
        }
        else
        {
            return value as! String
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try something like this:**

```
if let category = Stream["vote_status"] as? String {
                        print(category)
                    } else {
                        print(category)
                    }
```